# Android: Cannot resolve symbol 'compile'

Tags: compiler-errors, resolve

I was adding a new activity "Settings" with help from android studios Add New wizard. Right after that I get this

> Error:(47) A problem occurred evaluating project ':AppName'.
>   Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@395e73e7.

And it says cannot resolve symbol 'compile'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Check 'build.gradle' file. It probably has formatting errors where 'compile' is used.

Comment: In my case, the problem was introduced by Android Studio 1.3.2 Wizard.

Comment: In my case I had a comma after the previous dependency