# All compile lines in my module gradle file have shifted over when I make a new MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

As stated in the title. Whenever I've tried to make a new mapActivity by using File > New > Google > Google Maps Activity on Android Studio (Version: 2.1) , all the lines in the build.gradle file (module) have shifted over incorrectly by one line.

**Example**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'   
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
```

Becomes

```
compile
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'compile
'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'compile
'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'compile
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'compile
'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

}

Any Idea why this is? I also get an error, **"Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@7158ab94"**

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991832/could-not-find-property-compile-on-org-gradle-api-internal-artifacts-dsl-depen / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587847/android-cannot-resolve-symbol-compile

Answer (score 0):

Besides fixing all the lines in the build.gradle file (module). I also had to delete

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

from my build.gradle file (app) as it conflicted with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```